# PDO library with better parameter placement

Tags: php, pdo

Don't get me wrong PDO is great but what I don't like about it, is how variables are placed far away from the place they belong inside the SQL statement. Meaning I have a query like:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND pass = ?");
```

The variables that are replacing the `?` are always far away some lines below:

```
$stmt->bindParam(1, $email);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $pass);
```

If you have a lot of parameters this can get quite ugly. Using `:email` instead of `?` does not make it much better. Sometimes you see the parameters as array in the same methode like:

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND pass = ?",
   array($email, $pass));
```

A little bit better but with 10 variables it is still ugly. You practically create a variable `?` you only use once. Also code highlighting is not supported for this pseudo variable.

I think it would be nicer to have it like this

```
$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ", $email, " AND pass = ", $pass);
```

You could even include the parameters of `binParam()` like this:

```
$db->prepare_new(
   "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ", array($email, PDO::PARAM_STR),
   " AND pass = ", $pass);
```

I wounder if there is a library that supports this type of style. Do you know one?

Comment: These are just two methods ... you can write your own class that extends `PDO` and just write your custom methods, but with your version of prepare it will be hard to tell which string should be escaped and which should not be

Comment: Is it? First parameter is query, second is variable, query, variable, ... always alternating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If always every even parameter will be parameter you can do it like this:

```
class MyPDO extends PDO {
    public function prepareQuery() {
        $query_str = "";
        $params = array();
        foreach(func_get_args() as $key => $param) {
            if( $key % 2 == 0 ) {
                $query_str .= $param;
            }
            else {
                $params[] = $param;
                $query_str .= ' ? ';
            }
        }

        $prepared = $this->prepare($query_str);
        foreach( $params as $key => $param ) {
            $prepared->bindParam( $key+1, $param );
        }
        return $prepared;
    }
}
```

and then you can use it as you wanted:

```
$db = new MyPDO( .. );
$db->prepareQuery("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ", $email, " AND pass = ", $pass);
```

PS: not tested - just a concept

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the point of having `?` and `:email` is that you can reuse the query multiple times.  For example:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT true FROM user WHERE email = :email");
$stmt->execute(array($email1));
$stmt->execute(array($email2));
// etc.
```

Having specific variables in the query removes this functionality entirely.

If you wanted, you could always extend or comprise PDO, though:

```
class DB {
   private $pdo;

   public function executeQuery($query, $args) {
      $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
      $stmt->execute($args);
   }
}
$db->executeQuery("SELECT true FROM user WHERE email = :email", array($email1));
```

This hides the functionality of PDO that you dislike.

UPDATE:

This is an unusual way of doing things, but it seems to be what you're after:

```
$pdo->query("SELECT true FROM user WHERE email = " . $pdo->quote($email));
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php

Comment: Resuing the query is a nice but I almost never use it. 90% of my queries only run once. With the array as second parameter you get `$email1` closer but you still creating a pseudo variable.

Comment: @PiTheNumber updated my answer; if I were you I would get used to the more natural PDO functionality using bind/execute.

Comment: From the manual about quote: `If you are using this function to build SQL statements, you are **strongly** recommended to use PDO::prepare() to prepare SQL (...)`

Answer (score 0):

You could put something *similar* to this into a function:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND pass = :pass");

$arr = array(
    'email' => 'test@test.com',
    'pass' => 'secret'
);

foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    $stmt->bindParam(':'.$key, $val);

}
```

Example:

```
function myBindParams($stmt, $bindings){
     foreach($bindings as $key => $val){
        $stmt->bindParam(':'.$key, $val);
     }
     return $stmt;
}


$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND pass = :pass");

$arr = array(
    'email' => 'test@test.com',
    'pass' => 'secret'
);

$stmt = myBindParams($stmt, $arr);
```

Comment: Do you see what you do? You create a pseudo variable `email` to get `$email = 'test@test.com';` into your query. This pseudo variable is only used once, is not supported by your IDE (Highlighting) and hides what your are really inserting into the query.

Comment: I don't think it hides anything to be honest. Depends on how readable you consider associative arrays to be.

Comment: If I click on `$email` my IDE does show me where it is used. If I click on `:email` it does not. It might even not possible at all for the IDE to find out.